# Function to remove duplicates from a List | Python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function `remove_duplicates` to return only unique values from a list input. I tried to come up with some code but it is throwing infinite loop error. I am unable to understand why. The goal is not to achieve result as I have discovered there are direct methods like 'SET' to do this. But, I primarily wanted to understand my mistake as this is my first language and first day at any kind of coding.

```
def remove_duplicates(x):
    z = [x[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        y = i-1
        k = 0
        while y >= 0:
            if x[i] == x[y]:
               k = k + 1 
               y -= 1
        else:
            break
        if k == 0:
            z.append(x[i])
    return z
```

Comment: If not `x[i] == x[y]:` you never decrease `y` and get stuck in the loop.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't just use `in`, or a `set` to get rid of duplicates?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to understand loops by writing functions from scratch. Concepts are more important to me right now rather than dummy results. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 25):

Use the built-in python set capabilities.

```
y = list(set(x))
```

y will be a list of the unique elements of x. This works when the elements in x may be used in a set, so they have to implement `__eq__()` and `__hash__()`.

Answer (score 6):

It'll be good If you can use

> SET operator

to remove the duplicate elements from the list, like this:

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Now time to remove the duplicate elements from this list:

```
list(set(my_list))

Answer: [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: And now try this to de-deplify the list `[4,3,2,1]`. Or a list of lists.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with your code seem to be here:

```
while y >= 0:
    if x[i] == x[y]:
       k = k + 1 
       y -= 1
```

Here, you decrement `y` only if the current element was a match, otherwise you get into an infinite loop. Also, you have to remove the `else: break`, otherwise your add-loop will stop right after the first unique element in the list (i.e. after the first element)

If you want to stay true to your initial approach, you could try this:

```
def remove_duplicates(x):
    z = [x[0]]
    for i in range(1,len(x)):
        for y in range(0, i):
            if x[i] == x[y]:
                break
        else:
            z.append(x[i])
    return z
```

Note, however, that there are *much* simpler ways to ensure that the elements are unique. For instance, you can just use `in` to check whether the current element is already in the result list instead of checking each element individually.

```
def remove_duplicates(lst):
    res = []
    for x in lst:
        if x not in res:
            res.append(x)
    return res
```

If the elements are guaranteed to be hashable, you can also use a `set`. But don't do `return list(set(lst))`, as this will not preserve the order of the elements in the list. This is a bit more words, but faster than using `x not in res`.

```
def remove_duplicates(lst):
    seen = set()
    res = []
    for x in lst:
        if x not in seen:
            res.append(x)
            seen.add(x)
    return res
```

If you want a one-liner like this, you could use `OrderedDict` though:

```
import collections
def remove_duplicates(lst):
    return collections.OrderedDict(zip(lst, lst)).values()
```