# Python removing duplicates in list

Tags: python, duplicates

How can I remove duplicates from this list?
x = [name, code]

Some elements of list has the same code:
list = [['cafe', '/fr/48349066'], ['cafe', '/fr/48349056'], ['cafe', '/fr/48349066']]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python list subtraction operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428536/python-list-subtraction-operation)

Comment: @Diggy I tried set(x) and it doesn't work

Comment: 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7961363/removing-duplicates-in-lists

2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35731289/function-to-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-python

3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order

Comment: Please post a sample of what you've tried so far, and we'll try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a more processing-efficient way to do this, but this is the way I've always done stuff like this:

```
for i in range(len(list)):
    for j in range(len(list)):
        if list[i][1] == list[j][1]:
            list.pop(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to removing duplicates;

1-) The Naive Method;

```
new_list = [] 
for i in some_list: 
    if i not in new_list: 
        res.append(i)
```

2-) Using list comprehension;

```
new_list = [] 
[new_list.append(x) for x in some_list if x not in new_list]
```

3-) Using set();

```
some_list = list(set(some_list))
```

4-) Using collections.OrderedDict.fromkeys()

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
new_list = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(some_list))
```